# Angular 6 component interaction with reactive forms data

Tags: angular, angular6

I have 2 components lets say EmployeeInfo,CompanyInfo with each having reactive forms data(form controls) and in the 2nd component i have submit button.

My question is how can I collect form data from first component(EmployeeInfo)when i click on submit  button in the second component(CompanyInfo ) and send it to backend.(sending back end is not major issue but collecting data from the first component is the actual question).Could any body help me on this?

Comment: share your code as we can understand better

Comment: Thanks for the reply sneha. Currently I do not have code ready but basically I posted my requirement to proceed with development, based on the suggestion/better approach.

Comment: @Ravi, there' a "more natural" aproach to solve your problem, a component with two children: company-info and employed-info (see my answer)

Comment: Seems very good use case @Eliseo..Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using service. shared service would be a good option

**Your service**

```
public sharedEmployeeInfo = {};
```

**EmployeeInfo.HTML**

```
<form #EmployeeInfo="ngForm">
    .
    .
    <button (click)="SubmitEmployeeInfo(EmployeeInfo.value)">Submit</button>
<form>
```

**EmployeeInfo.TS**

```
import {sharedService} from './sharedService';

constructor(private shared:sharedService){}

SubmitEmployeeInfo(EmployeeInfo){
     // here you will set Employee data to your service object
     this.shared.sharedEmployeeInfo = EmployeeInfo;
}
```

Then in your CompanyInfo component

```
import {sharedService} from './sharedService';

constructor(private shared:sharedService){}

EmployeeData;

SubmitCompanydata(){
    // here you will get employee form data 
    this.EmployeeData = this.shared.sharedEmployeeInfo;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not have three components: the parent with a formGroup={EmployeeInfo,CompanyInfo}, and two childrens (each with a FormGroup with the data of Employ and Company). The parent has the boton submit

parent

```
<form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="submit()">
   <app-company-info [control]="myForm.get('companyInfo')"></app-company-info>
   <app-employee-info [control]="myForm.get('employeeInfo')"></app-employee-info>
   <button>submit</button>
</form>
{{myForm?.value|json}}

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}
  myForm=this.fb.group({
     companyInfo:this.fb.group({
         name:'',
         address:''

     }),
     employeeInfo:this.fb.group({
         firstName:'',
         secondName:''
     })
})
```

company-info

```
     <form *ngIf="control" [formGroup]="control">
        <input formControlName="name">
        <input formControlName="address">
     </form>

  @Input() control
```

employee-info

```
     <form *ngIf="control" [formGroup]="control">
        <input formControlName="firstName">
        <input formControlName="secondName">
     </form>

  @Input() control:FormGroup
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6us92?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-employee-info.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

This refers to communication between components or component interaction. In angular it can be done through [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#eventemitter). If there's a parent/child relation between your components, you can use EventEmitter like [this](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/angular-7-share-component-data-with-other-components-1b91d6f0b93f) using @Input and @Output properties. Otherwise if the components are independent (i.e. not parent/child), you can do the same but via an intermediary service, one component will call the service method to emit the event while second component will listen to the emission of the service. In case of service you should use BehaviorSubject or an Observable rather than an EventEmitter. Here's Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) on component interaction with all the possible ways along with the [live example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/component-interaction/stackblitz.html).

Comment: Thanks Ali,let me try those..could you provide any working stackbliz on this(in case if you find)

Comment: Hi Ravi, here's angular docs https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction on component interaction with all the possible ways along with the live example https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/component-interaction/stackblitz.html.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the way you can use,

**demo1.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
    Name: <input type="text" formControlName="firstName"/><br>
    Mobile:<input type="text" formControlName="lastName"/>
</form>
```

**demo1.component.ts**

```
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileForm.valueChanges
    .subscribe(form => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(form));
    }); 
  }
```

**demo2.component.html**

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" (click)="onSubmit()">
```

**demo2.component.ts**

```
onSubmit(){
   let vv = sessionStorage.getItem('form');
   let obj = JSON.parse(vv)
   if (obj != null) {
      alert('firstname: ' + obj.firstName + " lastname: " + obj.lastName);
   }
}
```

Live demo at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vs2xwc)

It would be better to encrypt data before store into sessionStorage/localStorage.

Comment: Welcome @Ravi, Additionally I have added stackbliz link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the suggestion/help,Here I am providing answer to my question based on my requirement and research based on that requirement so that i would be helpful for others.
1. Achieved sharing data between component using **Service**.
2.I am using multiple forms(getting user data) in each component and submitting all the data in final component,so the user can go at any form at any given time and modify the data for that,so I used **Observable** for that.
3.In my case I need tabs for collection data in different categories so used **mat-tab-group** for that.